# Angular Material Dialog With md-list-item ng-repeat scrolls to bottom upon load - After Upgrade

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I upgraded angular material from rc1 to 1.05.

Now the dialog is scrolling to the bottom of the list when my dialog loads.

Any ideas as to why it is scrolling to the bottom of the list.

Thanks

Comment: try adding a wrapper div to the dialog template

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late but I think I've figured out what is happening. 
$mdDialog has an option:

```
focusOnOpen - {boolean=}: An option to override focus behavior on open. Only
disable if focusing some other way, as focus management is required for 
dialogs to be accessible. Defaults to true.
```

This implies that to ensure the dialog is focused, something in the dialog is focused.

My experience of this is that the buttons at the bottom of the dialog where being focused by default, and thus the dialog was scrolling down to show them.

My fix was to add `md-autofocus` to the input I had at the top of the dialog.